# DYMOLA: opc server how to initialize using dsin.txt or a mat file using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opc, dymola

I created an OPC server in DYMOLA,
now I have this in DYMOSIM to click and initialize

using a ".MAT" file of a dsin.txt

Now I created a GUI file in MATLAB, and take input for variables and created a mat file

```
>>save FLUID_INITIALISE area volume density
```

Now I want to initialize this using MATLAB

I can do this

```
>>write(Initialize,1) //To initialize a previous data
```

I know can do this using dymola , SIMULATION > CONTINUE > IMPORT

BUT I WANT TO INITIALIZE IT USING MATLAB

normal MAT FILE LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
Aclass=['Atrajectory';'1.1        ';'           ';'binTrans   '];
data_1=[0,3600;100,100;50,50;5,5;100,100;90,90;10,10;10,10;10,10;10,10;10,10];
data_2=[];
dataInfo=[0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2;
         1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11     2     3;
         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0;
        -1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    -1    -1;];          
description=['TFFTTTHAVDS  ';'ieeeeeeroep  ';'meemmmaelne  ';'eddppptausc  ';'        mii  ';'ichchht[etf  ';'nooooorm yi  ';' ltltta^[ c  ';'[d d  n2m[   ';'s i ios]^kH  ';']ininuf 3ge  ';' n/n te ]/a  ';' /o [ r  mt  ';' ou[K[   ^   ';' utK]Kc  3[  ';' t ] ]o  ]J  ';'  [   e   k  ';' [k   f   g  ';' kg   f   ^  ';' g/   i   -  ';' /h   c   1  ';' h]   i   K  ';' ]    e   -  ';'      n   1  ';'      t   ]  ';'             ';'      [      ';'      k      ';'      g      ';'      /      ';'      K      ';'      m      ';'      ^      ';'      2      ';'      s      ';'      ^      ';'      2      ';'      ]      '];
name=['TFFTTTUAVDCTd';'ichchh roepce';'miiiio eln or';'e      aus  (';'        mi  T';'        et  c';'         y  o';'            )'];
save INITIALIZER Aclass data_1 data_2 dataInfo description name;
```

Comment: why someone voted it down!,

Comment: Please tell I will correct or in next post I will take care instead of just voting down

Comment: My guess is that people are offended by the all-caps title. All caps implies yelling. Use conventional style for best reception.

Comment: Thank You!! I have corrected it and will take care of it next time!

Comment: Seems to be a bit unfortunate timing, but Dymola 2021x discontinued OPC support: https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS/CATIA/DYMOLA/PDF/Dymola-2021x-release-notes.pdf -> page 46, section 3.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue what I did is,

I initialized dymola with default `dsin.txt` [which is created once you click simulate button]

then I write new values to them using this

```
write(area,20);
write(volume,30);
```

.. etc

Now

```
write(Run,1)
```